# Non-XA transactions

Tags: spring, hibernate, jta, websphere-8, xa

#### Situation:

We have a web application (Spring, Hibernate) running on WAS 8.5 against 3 different DBs. They are in 2 different geographical locations.
Location A: Master Data DB (XA resource).
Location B: MD Replica DB (R/O Purposes, Non-XA resource) + Operational DB (XA resource).

We use Last Participant Support so we can include MD Replica DB in Global Transactions (JTA). Transactions are demarcated using annotations on service methods (which, in turn use services and/or DAOs configured to access either of the 3 DBs).
There are only a few operations that require writing both to Operational and MD DBs. We intend to get rid of them (as distribuded transactions).

#### Question:

We want to get rid of XA (so, use only non-XA JDBC drivers) without rewriting the application.
Is there an alternative to Global Transactions in WAS? Would ActivitySessions apply? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

It is still possible to use global transactions with non-XA resources due to Last Participant Optimization (LPO) but you are limited to 1 non-XA resource per global transaction with LPO.  So you can still use 1 non-XA data source and have it in a global transaction, but a 1-resource global transaction sort of defeats the purpose of using a global transaction in the first place.

For JDBC resources, having an XA data source is the only way to participate in a multi-resource global transaction without LPO.  For example, to have 2 data sources participate in the same global transaction, at least one of them must be an XADataSource.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer.

This is what I suspected, but I was rather wondering whether WAS had some other transaction manager or transaction manager config / mode that behaved in a different way (maybe ActivitySessions?).

I know that, for distributed transaction management, different approaches exist other than XA/2PC. Maybe they offer different or lower guarantees [1].

Regards,

[1] http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077963/open-source-tools/distributed-transactions-in-spring--with-and-without-xa.html

Comment: I think you have three options:  1) Global transactions (XA).  2) what JEE refers to as the unspecified transaction context, in WAS this is often referred to as a local transaction.  Using a non-XA datasource will allow you to have as many resources as you want but they will not commit or backout atomically.  You get this behavior by changing the TX attribute on EJBs, or by not starting a global tran.  3) Activity Sessions / Compensation.  Here you have to code your own recovery logic if something goes wrong.  This is a lot of work, I would not recommend this approach for an existing app.

Comment: I guess I'd have to check my Spring/Hibernate config in case something can be done at that level. I would't like to have to start new transactions through Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW. Perhaps someone else has gone through the same issue?